# Как запустить версию проекта Vue.js созданного с использованием команды 'npm run build' (vue-cli)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Для создания проекта я использовал vue-cli. Запустив команду 'npm run build' я получил готовую для использования сборку. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустив файл index.html в браузере я увидел пустое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое моего index.html файла. Вроде бы никаких ошибок нет:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>cv</title>
    <style type=text/css>
       html, body{
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
       }</style>
    <link href='/static/css/app.b3ceb6191281c6a4dd333aa0b8aed7cd.css' rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=app>
    </div>

    <script type=text/javascript src='/static/js/manifest.488e7f096afe65619705.js'></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src='/static/js/vendor.fa2e9b388f427a714cca.js'></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src='/static/js/app.d3d1742ab1cad95402a6.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Что нужно сделать что бы файл index.html отобразился в браузере?

Comment: вопросы тут задаются на русском языке

Comment: nothing... just double click on this file should run index.html in browser.
What kind of answer u have, when u tried to run it?

Comment: @Oleksandr I added picture with browser massage. Pleas look on it.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko your index.html file doesn't find js and css files.
Lokk into your path in .html file to them. Is it correct?

Comment: Перепишите вопрос на русском, вы на специальном русскоязычном сайте stackexchange.

Comment: @Oleksandr Я прикрепил к вопросу содержимое index.html. С виду ошибок нет

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko как нету? у вас индекс.хтмл в папке statistic, пропишите путь так  `js/app.d3d1742ab1cad95402a6.js'`. И так для css файлов.

Comment: @Oleksandr Нет, index.html находится в папке 'dist'. В ней же находится папка 'static' в которой находятся все все прикрепленные файлы. На картинке прикрепленной  к вопросу это видно. Возможно вы просто не заметили.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko http://joxi.ru/EA44aj1tWdoOAb я по этой линии смотрел, а если в дист, то все равно у вас не верный путь, уберите `/` перед `static`

Comment: @Oleksandr Ваш совет помог. Файлы подключились к index.html. Но сразу же возник следующий вопрос. В проекте, на странице есть изображения. Судя по следующей ошибке в консоле браузераб пути к ним так же сгенерированны неправильно. Подскажите как сказать vue-cli генерировать проект 'build' с правильными ссылками? П.С. Все изображенияв проекта я подключаю при помощи require('...'). Пример из проекта: <img class="APP-HEADER-IMG"                      :src='require("./assets/img/AppHeader.png")' alt="fon"                     @load="ShowNameAndSwitchersOnPage">

Comment: require("./assets/img/AppHeader.png") видите что из себя предсатвляет "путь"?? Перепишите под ваши нужны убрав `/` или добавив необходимые данные в путь

Comment: @OlegShleif я пробовал менять путь. После выполнения команды 'npm run build' он автоматически форматируется. Это не помогает. Я решил проблему ванадальским образом. Залез в в один из js файлов build сборки. Понаходил все ссылки на изображения вставленные в проект. И удалил переменную, которая контактерировалась с строкой содержащей путь к изображению. В итоге все заработало в браузере без сервера как я и хотел. Но хотелось бы в следующий раз получить тот же результат более простым путем. Подозреваю что вся причина в настройках WebPack. Но я не знаю что нужно в них изменить.

Comment: А если попробовать не средствами vue подключать? Просто <img src='*Нужный путь*'>

Answer (score 1):

В index.html путь нужно указывать так `./static/...`